# Why I am not getting same values for exported simulink variables as stepinfo?

Tags: signal, control-system, signal-processing, matlab, simulink

I am using MATLAB 2015a and I am trying to get stepinfo parameters of output that was exported from Simulink to MATLAB workspace but I am not getting same values as if try to get stepinfo for MATLAB implementation of same system.

MATLAB code is

```
clc;clear;close all
num=[1]
den=[1 1]
num1=[10]
den1=[1 1]
sys1=tf(num1,den1)
num2=[1]
den2=[2 0.5]
sys2=tf(num2,den2)
sys_series=series(sys1,sys2)
sys_feedback=feedback(sys_series,0.1)
sys=series(540,sys_feedback)
sys_cl=feedback(sys,1)
stepinfo(sys_cl)
```

I get output of last line as shown below:

```
    RiseTime: 0.0202
    SettlingTime: 6.2294
     SettlingMin: 0.0728
     SettlingMax: 1.9624
       Overshoot: 96.2920
      Undershoot: 0
            Peak: 1.9624
        PeakTime: 0.0605
```

[Snap of simulink model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSHiV.png)

Command for getting stepinfo parameters variable exported from simulink to MATLAB workspace:

```
 stepinfo(simout.Data,simout.Time)
```

I get following output

```
      RiseTime: 0.0217
    SettlingTime: 9.9387
     SettlingMin: 0.0947
     SettlingMax: 1.9313
       Overshoot: 91.1432
      Undershoot: 0
            Peak: 1.9313
        PeakTime: 1.0556
```

Other values are almost approximately same but there is big difference in **settling time** and **overshoot**. Why?

I tried changing the Step time of Step block in simulink from default value(1) to zero, but no big change seen.

Google drive link for this simulink file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1syRszTLq-9XiixagmAP6QBBcrYZStbOi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What are the integration parameters used in simulink? Variable step? what is the minimum step size? What happens if you set the simulink `minimum step size` as `0.00001s`? If the default `step time` was `1s` then that explains the `1.0556s` versus `0.0605s` in the `peak time` parameter.

Comment: Try to include all relevant details in the question body itself; The external links may stop working in the future, which may make this question useless for future readers. Fewer people would be inclined to follow external links. This would reduce the chances of getting an answer.